# Find the business related to a Facebook App through the API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

Since Facebook introduced API V2.0, there is the new [Business Mapping API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business) that let us associate a Facebook App to a [Business](https://www.facebook.com/business). One of the great feature is the new `token_for_business` field :

> Once an app has been associated with a Business Manager, you may request the token_for_business field on the User node. This returns a string which is the same for this person across all the apps managed by the same Business Manager.

I want to take advantage of that in my code. The thing is, my code is likely to be executed with several Facebook App, and a check on the app config is needed.

To ensure the things won't go wrong, i want to check if the app belongs to the good Business. How can i do that through the graph API? I have an app access_token, but I can't find a way to read that property. Is that possible ?

[The documentation on the `application` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application) lets me think that it's not, but I know that the doc can be incomplete, especially for the new features !

Comment: Docs mention a `company` field: “The company the app belongs to”. It’s a string, so presumably the company name?

Comment: @CBroe, no, it's for the `Publisher` field in the "App Info" page

Comment: Well, then it seems there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it the other way around by checking the connected objects of the business.

```
You can retrieve all Facebook objects (e.g. pages, apps, etc) where an Ad User is an administrator (or developer/advertiser) for a specific business:

    curl -G\
    -d "business_id=<business_id>" \
    -d "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/connectionobjects"
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/v2.3#connection-objects